# Can I burn a DVD with the "Disc At Once (DAO)" setting using Brasero?

Tags: brasero

I prefer to always burn data discs with DAO setting to get a reliable burn & wide-compatibility across players.

I can find no DAO setting option in Brasero. What setting is Brasero using to burn data DVDs? And can it be set to burn using DAO (Disc at Once)?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use k3b since I find this a more reliable burner.

For Brasero, I think you need to burn your files to an ISO first.

Then from the terminal you can burn to DVD via a command:

```
cdrecord --dao myisofilename.iso
```